# Model not making it to controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am having some difficulties getting my Model to my controller.  Now I do not know if this is an important point, but this system does not have a database per say.  It uses an API I have built to insert its data into an external systems database.  I had to design it this way for numorous reasons.

Anyways, I have my Models set up (even though they dont have their own database) and then my route is like so

```
Route::model('projects', 'Project');
Route::bind('projects', function($value, $route) {
    return App\Project::whereId($value)->first();
});
Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectController');
```

Now everything I need to do works besides the update.  Now I have an update form which opens like so

```
{!! Form::model($project, [
   'class'=>'form-horizontal',
   'method' => 'PATCH',
   'route' => ['projects.update', $project->id]
]) !!}
```

If I output `$project` I see what I expect to see.  This calls my update function which is currently like this

```
public function update(Request $request, Project $project)
{
    dd($project);
}
```

The $request object is fine, I can see all the inputs.  However, `$project` is empty.  Am I missing something obvious here or do I need a table for this to work?

Any information appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Should `Route::model('projects', 'Project')` be `Route::model('projects', 'App\Project')` ?

Comment: Shouldnt have to do that, never done it in the past.

Comment: Yes it should. Read the docs for this they are pretty cleAr https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding. I don't think you need both model and bind, and also the second parameter of $route you are passing through isn't needed